# How to optimize the search on recent records

Tags: elasticsearch

We use ElasticSearch to store historical search data. The index is designed to split by day from a template. All fields are static, the searchable fields are indexed, the rest are disabled.

This index is both very-frequently updated and searched. The update is to add documents into it; the search is to retrieve 500 most recent historical records. It performs fine with low-workload but when we put it under stress test (such as 150 update + search actions per second), it starts to perform 5x slower.

The size of the index is not huge, about 1GB per day. We rotate the data on a 30 day basis.

We provisioned an ES cluster including 1 master node (4VCPU, 8GB RAM) and 5 data nodes (8VCPU, 24GB RAM) for this. Considering the index size, we set shard = 0 and replicas = 4. On each data node, we let ES use 12GB RAM and the other 12 GB is assigned to heap.

We tried something like increasing refresh intervals and it did not seem to work: if the load is light, the search time is 30 ms; when the load is high, it can jump to 220 ms.

I checked the cache situation and it is terrible:

```
 "primaries": {
    "query_cache": {
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
      "total_count": 7883586,
      "hit_count": 0,
      "miss_count": 7883586,
      "cache_size": 0,
      "cache_count": 0,
      "evictions": 0
    }
  },
  "total": {
    "query_cache": {
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
      "total_count": 39982611,
      "hit_count": 14,
      "miss_count": 39982597,
      "cache_size": 0,
      "cache_count": 6,
      "evictions": 6
```

It is possible that every setup of this is non-optimal, so I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: `retrieve 500 most recent historical records` you could try index sorting by the field you use to search upon. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules-index-sorting.html . The refresh interval is a double edged sword. Increasing it a lot could help, but it could also cause spikes during the refresh itself (since the work it needs to do will be more).

Comment: So basically you search only the active index and not the other rolled/frozen indices? Am I correct? If yes and you are using the latest elasticsearch check the freeze index api https://www.elastic.co/blog/creating-frozen-indices-with-the-elasticsearch-freeze-index-api

Comment: If you go with index sorting, depending on the number of shards you might encounter the bouncing results problem, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_search_options.html

Comment: @alkis, thanks for your reply. I read about the frozen index however we're limited to use ES 6.2, which does not include this feature. I think the index sorting makes sense, I'll try it out, thanks a lot.